# Calculated Column using DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a TABLE showing whole month - Ticket Opened Start Date like this (`2015-07-28 06:40:52:337`) and Ticket Close End Date like this (`2015-07-29 07:45:52:337`).

Using T-SQL `DATEDIFF()` I want to find out the difference in `DAYS`, `HOURS`, `MINUTES`, and `SECS` and put it in a new calculated column called `TimeDiff`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT  CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, [Opened Start Date], [Close End Date]) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' Day(s), ' +
        CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, [Opened Start Date], [Close End Date]) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' Hour(s), ' +
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [Opened Start Date], [Close End Date]) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' Minute(s), ' +
        CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [Opened Start Date], [Close End Date]) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' Second(s), ' AS TimeDiff
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: That's really not what someone would expect to have in a such column. The result is totally wrong (e.g. 2015-07-30 23:59 - 2015-07:31 00:01 is one day), and the seconds are total seconds, so if the ticket is open a week your column will say "7 Day(s), 168 Hour(s), 10080 Minute(s), 604800 Second(s), " or would if you would have reserved enough space for the seconds, it won't fit to varchar(5) anymore

Comment: And that's not even a calculated column, that's just a select clause

Comment: My understanding from the question is OP needs this time difference in days, hours, mins and secs separated from each other but if he needs them together you are right.

Comment: Even that would be wrong because datediff doesn't do what you would expect from the name. "Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    [starttime] datetime, [endtime] datetime,
    TimeDiff as 
    convert(varchar(3), (DATEDIFF(SECOND, [starttime], [endtime])/86400)) + ' Days, ' +
    convert(varchar(2), ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, [starttime], [endtime])%86400)/3600)) + ' Hours, ' +
    convert(varchar(2), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, [starttime], [endtime])%86400)%3600)/60)) + ' Minutes, ' +
    convert(varchar(2), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, [starttime], [endtime])%86400)%3600)%60)) + ' Seconds',
);
```

This calculates all the differences in seconds and calculates each of the time parts from there.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45ba3/1)